# Is it possible to create Ubuntu Persistent Storage file on a hard disk

Tags: persistence

I've been using Puppy linux for a while and i'm interested on trying Ubuntu. is it possible to create a Persistent Storage the same way Puppy use?

puppy saves changes to a file on my hard disk and access that file every time i boot from the cd. no need to make a partition or format the drive.

I've searched the forum but didn't find a answer.

Comment: I am actually using something like that. I created a `chroot environment` on disk, and then I installed kernel and grub, finally applied this patch https://github.com/lemonsqueeze/boot_chroot . Now I can boot into a directory which contains a linux distribution. I also managed anather way in Ubuntu 14.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/405735/installing-multiple-linux-distros-in-a-single-partition/409229#409229

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are basically three ways to run Ubuntu:

- live-only booted from a DVD disk or USB drive
- persistent live booted from a DVD disk or USB drive
- Installed system (installed into internal drive or external drive (USB hard disk drive or pendrive or eSATA drive).

If I understand correctly, you are thinking about 'persistent live drive', and yes, you can create such a system in a USB hard disk drive (even in an internal hard disk drive), if you use mkusb. The partition for persistence will be created in the target drive (in the drive where the operating system is installed), but you can change that manually afterwards. The overlay system for persistence will search for a file/partition with the name/label 'casper-rw', and can find it in another drive too.

See the following links.

- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

---

But you should also consider 'Installed system in a USB hard disk drive' according to the following link and links from it,

[Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. i will try booting from external drive.      However i'm trying to use this on my office pc and having plugged in a ext drive not that easy and flash drives are slow